# Android: Connect to website, Authenticate, Send Info, Receive Info

Tags: java, android, http

I'm working on a project for school and have ready many different tutorials online but, I cannot get anything to work.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html has been the most help but, none of these tutorials point you in the direction you need when you need to submit credentials to access the webpage.

My code for credentials is:

```
CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure If I'm going about this the correctly as it is my first time trying to connect my app to an outside source.

I have all of my php on the server configured correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up submitting my credentials through a php query `http://site.com/?username=me&pass=myPass$1234`